# Is my Sudoku algorithm considered an "expert system"?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, expert-system

I wrote a code which has all the rules of Sudoku written into it (one occurence of a digit per column, line, and square). The code takes an input (unfilled sudoku grid), and returns a solution by translating logical clauses into DIMACS format and using a SAT solver.

Given that the algorithm respects rules, takes in data, and uses that data to form conclusion based on implications (eg if there is a 1 in the first cell, there cannot be a 1 in the second cell), is this code considered an "expert system"? Thank you.

Comment: If you're talking to the media and/or trying to get funding for your startup company, then yes, definitely it's an expert system. OTOH, if you're talking to engineers/scientists then it's yet another Sudoku solver, nothing more.

Comment: @user3386109 Ahah, I see. The reason I'm asking isn't really to try and stroke my ego.; I'm trying to truly understand what it means for something to be an expert system, and if an algorithm such as the one I've described would fit that definition. You are correct though, it's nothing more than your run-of-the-mill Sudoku solver.

Comment: The problem with the term *"expert system"* is that it's more hype than substance. People using the term are generally over-selling the technology. The truth behind an expert system is that it's a large database that's accessed through a customized search engine. One example is a medical "expert system". The system has a large database of diseases. The doctor enters a list of patient symptoms and test results. The search engine then generates a list of possible diseases. It may also suggest additional tests to be performed, or drugs to try. Bottom line: it's just another search engine.

Comment: @user3386109 Huh, I never thought about it that way, but I suppose you're right. On the other hand, by that very logic, couldn't you say that the algorithm I've proposed is just another search engine? I don't mean to be cheeky.

Comment: I suppose that you could say that it's searching for the solution, but I don't see a large database. If I were implementing Sudoku as an expert system, I would create a **database** of every Sudoku solution that has ever been published. When presented with a new Sudoku, the **search engine** would look for any solution that contains the given numbers at the given locations. The search engine would be **customized** to recognize rotations, mirroring, and substitutions (e.g. changing 3 to 1, 1 to 5, and 5 to 3 doesn't change the puzzle).

Comment: This of course would be a really bad way to implement a Sudoku solver. It uses lots of space to store the database, takes more time than other solvers, and ultimately fails if no matching solution is found. But it would qualify as an expert system.

Comment: @user3386109 Ah, I think I'm starting to get it. The idea behind an expert system isn't really to have rules form which you can deduce a possible solution, but rather having a lot of data which says 'if your input matches this data, then it your solution could be this'. As a result, having large amounts of data will usually point you toward an accurate solution. Am I wrong? Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: I think you've got it. But beware of misinformed media types, and fast-talking salesmen :)

Comment: @user3386109 Oh I am trying. The number of futurist mumbo-jumbo rubbish articles I usually have to sift through before I find something of substance is quickly weighing on my soul. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a program is an expert system is subjective, but I'd say unless your program is encoding non-trivial knowledge acquired from a domain expert, it's not an expert system. If you can't teach another person to practically do what your program is doing, it's not an expert system.

By that definition, what you've done is probably not an expert system since it would be too time consuming for a person to use the same technique. I've written a sudoku solver using a production system (https://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/code/HEAD/tree/branches/63x/examples/sudoku/) that I would consider to be an expert system. The encoded knowledge was acquired from websites with advanced techniques for humans to use for solving sudoku puzzles. All of the encoded techniques can be practically used by humans for solving puzzles (although some of the more complex techniques push that boundary).

Although my sudoku solver can solve much more complicated puzzles than I could, calling it an expert system is not an indication of its sophistication. There are better approaches for solving extremely complex sudoku puzzles than emulating approaches humans might take.

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me on this question as well. Generally speaking, then, is it safe to assume that expert systems as they are defined, are not really all that useful in video games? Wouldn't NPC's usually be programmed using a non-expect rule-based system, or even a finite-state automaton?

Comment: By the definition I'm giving, a production system used in a game isn't likely to be an expert system. It's better to describe it by a more objective term such as rule-based, finite state machine, or neural network depending upon the underlying technology used for the NPC logic.

Comment: I see. One last question, then I'll leave you alone. Based on the description of my code, would this solver be considered a rule-based system? On one hand, it uses rules to form conclusions with which it solves a problem. On the other, the machine isn't really being fed continuous information, which is unlike what I've seen from most examples of rule-based systems; it recieves a puzzle and returns a solution. Thanks!

Comment: From your description it sounds more like constraint programming or logic programming than rule-based programming. Rule-based programming doesn't have exclusive use of the word rule, but I think it might be confusing to some to call your program a rule-based system when the rules don't have the ability to explicitly add or remove data.

Comment: When you say add or remove data, you mean the conclusions that the machine comes to when certain conditions are met, that the machine then stores?

Comment: No, I mean the rules changing data.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to come off as rude. Could you give me an example of what you mean when you say that the rules change data?

Comment: if the subject of the message contains "Nigerian Prince" then set the mailbox of the message to Junk

Comment: Ah, I see. In the email examplen, the data that goes into the working memory is changed. In my algorithm, any data coming in is only served to come up with a solution, but remains unchanged. Thanks a lot for all your help. It's  quite difficult to truly grasp an idea simply by looking at its definition. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Exactly. In Sudoku, a statement such as a number can't appear more than once in a row is more accurately described as a constraint rather than rule in a programming sense, but in a general sense (as in telling someone how to solve a sudoku puzzle) most people are going to call that a rule.

Answer (score 0):

In the 80's, I had written a clone of the Emycin expert system engine. One important characteristic was the ability for the user to ask **WHY** the expert system got some conclusion. The system could reply (in an almost natural language) that it applied such and such rules to get to the conclusion.

With this kind of system, the knowledge is modeled and implemented (by a cognitician engineer) as an explicit set of rules. These rules are objects known by the engine. The engine can trigger the rules (forward or backward or maybe using metarules...) and can log the triggered rules and thus explain its conclusions.

(this is my sense for expert systems).